# Limit EditText text length

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm trying to do it but I get a "Stack Overflow error" so I accepted the advice and came here searching for help.

I want to limit the lenght of the text the user can insert, so when he type a character above the length limit the character is erased

```
sms_input.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            String cs = sms_input.getText().toString();
            if (cs.length() > 160) { sms_input.setText(cs.substring(0, MAX_MSG_LENGTH + 1)); }

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });
```

Logcat:

```
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733): java.lang.StackOverflowError
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at android.graphics.Paint.getTextRunAdvances(Paint.java:1754)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at android.graphics.Paint.getTextRunAdvances(Paint.java:1720)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at android.text.MeasuredText.addStyleRun(MeasuredText.java:164)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at android.text.MeasuredText.addStyleRun(MeasuredText.java:204)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at android.text.StaticLayout.generate(StaticLayout.java:281)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at android.text.DynamicLayout.reflow(DynamicLayout.java:284)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at android.text.DynamicLayout.(DynamicLayout.java:170)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at android.widget.TextView.makeSingleLayout(TextView.java:5986)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at android.widget.TextView.makeNewLayout(TextView.java:5884)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6423)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3696)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3554)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3529)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at com.easyray.lemon.SmsChat$5.afterTextChanged(SmsChat.java:211)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7247)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3703)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3554)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3529)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at com.easyray.lemon.SmsChat$5.afterTextChanged(SmsChat.java:211)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7247)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3703)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3554)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3529)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at com.easyray.lemon.SmsChat$5.afterTextChanged(SmsChat.java:211)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7247)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3703)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3554)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3529)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at com.easyray.lemon.SmsChat$5.afterTextChanged(SmsChat.java:211)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7247)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3703)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3554)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3529)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at com.easyray.lemon.SmsChat$5.afterTextChanged(SmsChat.java:211)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7247)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3703)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3554)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3529)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at com.easyray.lemon.SmsChat$5.afterTextChanged(SmsChat.java:211)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7247)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3703)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3554)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3529)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at com.easyray.lemon.SmsChat$5.afterTextChanged(SmsChat.java:211)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7247)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3703)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3554)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3529)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at com.easyray.lemon.SmsChat$5.afterTextChanged(SmsChat.java:211)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7247)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3703)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3554)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3529)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at com.easyray.lemon.SmsChat$5.afterTextChanged(SmsChat.java:211)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7247)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3703)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3554)
09-25 17:07:34.972: E/AndroidRuntime(22733):    at android.w

Comment: Can you please give a description of your problem along with the code ?

Comment: done it, I must have accidentally deleted it

Comment: What error are you getting ? `Stack Overflow Error` ? Really? Can we please see your LogCat ?

Comment: done it, but I can't post logcat properly, sorry

Comment: Not a problem. I edited it to make it more readable. Check the answer below. At least now you know why it is happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to do all these. Just try this in XML

```
android:maxLength="120"
```

When you try to enter more than 120 characters it just block you from entering the next character.

I think this is what you looking for. Just leave it if not.

Answer (score 3):

This same question was already answered before for example here ([TextWatcher afterTextChanged causes stackoverflow in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8628437/textwatcher-aftertextchanged-causes-stackoverflow-in-android))

But basically what happens is that you change the text inside the method "afterTextChanged" and that triggers the method to be called again, thus originating the infinite loop ending with the StackOverflow exception :)

Comment: Firstly, +1 for giving the nice explanation. I am wondering how to resolve this. What if the check was done for 1 less than the maxLength and when it was found to have reached that, the setText method would set the string (which is still one less than the maxLength) and then disable the EditText and maybe also remove the TextWatcher associated with it ?

Comment: One possible solution would be to remove the watcher using "removeTextChangedListener", set the text and then adding the listener again.

Comment: is there any other way to obtain the same effect? maybe the approach is wrong.

It would be useful if I can make textwatcher not call ontextchanged if the lenght > max_lenght

Comment: Why don't you use "InputFilter.LengthFilter(160)"? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.html

Comment: LengthFilter is sweet! I wish I could upvote your answer again!